# NLTK - Getting the list of PoS tags from the Brown corpus

Tags: python

In the NLTK Brown Corpus, each word is presented together with its correspondent PoS tags, as shown below (where `'AT, 'NP-TL'...` would be the tags):

```
nltk.corpus.brown.tagged.words()

[('The', 'AT'), ('Fulton', 'NP-TL'), ...]
```

I would like to get a list of all these tags (one tag per line) without the words they accompany. For example:

```
AT
NP-TL
...
```

Does anyone know the function I would need to use in order to ONLY access the tags and not the words?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need a map to access to every second element of a tuple, this is not nltk related

you can do it with a for loop

```
l = [('The', 'AT'), ('Fulton', 'NP-TL')]
expected_list = [tuple[1] for tuple in l]
```

This comprehension list store the second element of each tuple present in the list (Which is the tag)

You can also do it with a map and a lambda function.
A map is applying the lambda function to every element of the list (Here you get the second element of each tuple)

In python3, a map is returning a map object, you need to convert into a list if you want to use it as a list

```
l = [('The', 'AT'), ('Fulton', 'NP-TL')]
expected_list = list(map(lambda x: x[1], l))
```

After getting your list, you can print all your answers on a new line easily with the print(*) method (Python3 only)

```
print(*expected_list, sep='\n')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Could you please expand it a bit? I'm new to Python and I don't know what a map is.

Comment: Thanks for adding more info!

Comment: Is everything clear? If no do not hesitate to ask for more, if yes, can you please accept the answer? I appreciate